# Can not use ray datasets map_batches function to update database (a class object obtained by langchain)？

Tags: python, langchain, ray, faiss

I want to update the database (a class object obtained by langchain.FAISS) with new data use ray.

But I can not obtain the updated database even if it has been updated in the function.

This is a demo:

```py
from langchain.vectorstores import FAISS
from langchain.embeddings import OpenAIEmbeddings
import ray

# load data
json_path = "demo.jsonl"
demo_data = ray.data.read_json(json_path)

# get embedding
embedding_model = OpenAIEmbeddings()

# init database
db = FAISS.from_texts(["start"],embedding_model)

# update database
def update_db(batch):
    global db
    db.add_texts(batch['text'])
    # log the db 
    print(len(db.docstore._dict))
    return {}

demo_data.map_batches(
    update_db,
    batch_size=10,
    compute=ActorPoolStrategy(size=1)).count()

# log the updated db
print("-----")
print(len(db.docstore._dict))
```

If the demo_data has 100 rows, the print info is show as follows:

```
(MapWorker(MapBatches(storechunks)) pid=389980) 11
(MapWorker(MapBatches(storechunks)) pid=389980) 21
(MapWorker(MapBatches(storechunks)) pid=389980) 31
  ...

(MapWorker(MapBatches(storechunks)) pid=389980) 101

-----

1
```

I want to know why the db object can't be updated globally?

Did I do something wrong?

Thank you very much for your reply！

The demo.jsonl likes this :

```
{"text":"a demo"}
{"text":"one demo"}
{"text":"two demo"}
{"text":"three demo"}
{"text":"four demo"}
{"text":"five demo"}
```